# how to deal with daylight saving in hourly logs

Tags: logback, dst

Am using logback xml to configure logging. I want the logs to be rolled over on an hourly basis. How would the behaviour be when daylight saving occurs?When the clock is advanced by an hour the logfile corresponding to that hour, does it get skipped?
 When the clock is reverted by an hour, does the hourly file get overwritten?
What is the way to work around this?

Comment: My guess is that it could be done in UTC (thus no switching except for leap seconds). But it's only a guess.

Comment: I'm not familiar with logback, but in general, logging in UTC instead of local time is always a good recommendation.  DST is just one reason.  The other is being able to correlate logs from servers in multiple time zones.

Comment: yes..utc would be ideal..
adding the file name pattern with hour in UTC like  <fileNamePattern>${filteredLogFileName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH,Etc/UTC}</fileNamePattern> 
is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Yes..as pointed put by @volodya and @Matt, logging in UTC format would be the ideal solution,